# Firebase Device Registration ID

Tags: python, django, cordova-plugin-fcm

How do I get the Registration ID for FCM to send push notification?

I want to fetch it from my PYTHON code or from JAVASCRIPT.

```
{'multicast_ids': [5315390988252285793], 'success': 0, 'failure': 1, 'canonical_ids': 0, 'results': [{'error': 'InvalidRegistration'}], 'topic_message_id': None}
```

Comment: what is your Registration ID?

Comment: That is the question, I have no idea what a registration ID is suppose to be and how to extract it.

Comment: Would it be one part of your dataset(in your provided case, dictionary)? and do you know how does it look like(for example **registration_ids**)?

Comment: Well no, I was studying i just got a small idea that it is send fromthe client side so it may be the actual 'device registration number' type something, but still it unresolved right now!